# warnings and errors when starting emacs

Tags: bash, emacs, osx-elcapitan, terminal.app

I have a few annoying warnings that appear when I start emacs:

```
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs-x86_64-10_9 --
daemon=/tmp/green

Warning: arch-dependent data dir '/Users/build/workspace/Emacs-Multi-Build/label/mavericks/emacs-source/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/libexec/': No such file or directory
starting ~/.emacs.d/init.el
ad-handle-definition: ‘tramp-read-passwd’ got redefined
ending ~/.emacs.d/init.el
Starting Emacs daemon.
```

How can I get rid of the tramp related warning and the "No such file" messages?

My setup is running:
emacs 25.1 mostly on -nw mode and daemon/client mode
osx 10.11.4
osx terminal with bash shell

Comment: How did you come about finding your binary -- did you download it from the tried and true:  https://emacsformacosx.com/  Or did you build it yourself?  You can build Emacs without dependencies and it won't look for anything extra when you launch it.

Comment: i didnt build it myself, downloded from https://emacsformacosx.com/builds

Comment: Consider submitting a bug report to the maintainer about the `arch-dependent data dir . . .` warning message.  As to the other message about `tramp-read-passwd`, search through your user-configuration and third-party installed libraries for that function -- that won't happen with **Emacs -Q**, so it's something you have done post-build (or permitted to be done . . .).  It may not be necessary to redefine that function.

Comment: `ad-handle-definition: ‘tramp-read-passwd’ got redefined` means that you (or a library you've loaded) has defined some *advice* for `tramp-read-passwd` (which necessarily redefines the function for that symbol), and that the thing being advised was loaded subsequently to the advice being evaluated. It's rather unlikely to be something you need to worry about. You can use `C-h f tramp-read-passwd` to find out more about the advice in question.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have some environment variables set like `EMACSPATH` which if set needs to be a directory.